# How to transfer data from one component to another in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

There is a code that displays posts and by clicking on a post shows the full content of this post.

```
import React from "react";


type respX = {
    "id": any,
    "userId": any,
    "title": any,
    "body": any,
}

interface PropsI {
}

interface StateI {
    data: respX[];
    changedBody: string
    changedTitle: string
}

export class ComponentPostList extends React.Component<PropsI, StateI> {

    state: StateI = {data: [], changedBody: '', changedTitle: 'Click to choose article'}

    async getPostById(id: any) {
        const myResponse = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
        const myJson = await myResponse.json();
        this.setState({changedBody: myJson.body, changedTitle: myJson.title});
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/`);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({data: json});
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="About">
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="title">{this.state.changedTitle}</div>
                    <div className="article">{this.state.changedBody}</div>
                </div>
                {this.state.data.map(el => (
                    <li onClick={e => this.getPostById(el.id)} key={el.id}>
                        {el.title}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How to transfer data from one component to another? To render the post headers in one component, and already the full content of the post in another component. These components are on the same level:

```
  <ComponentPostList data = {data} onClick = (getPostById) />
  <ComponentArticle post = {post} />
```

Comment: Have you tried Context API?

Comment: @Reza Ghorban No, I didn`t.. Is it necessary to use it here?

Comment: No, but it's an option.

Comment: "lift state up" - by state in parent of both

Comment: in `getPostById` function you can send your post data to parent of `ComponentPostList` and `ComponentArticle` , and store it to state and then pass as props to `ComponentArticle`

Comment: @Reza Hashemi Right. I meant this logic when I asked a question. But unfortunately I do not know how to do this in code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use a callback function in this case. It's a simple way to solve your problem.

You have 2 components. You can pass a function to a child component to receive a value from a child component back to their parent.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = { post: null, data: null }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await fetchData()
    this.setState({ data })
  }

  getPostById = async (id: any) => {
    const myResponse = await fetch(url);
    const post = await myResponse.json();
    this.setState({ post });
  }

  render() {
    <ComponentPostList 
      data={this.state.data} 
      postTitle={this.state.post.title} 
      changedBody={this.state.post.changedBody} 
      handleClick={this.getPostById}
    />
    <ComponentArticle postBody={this.state.post ? this.state.post.body : ''} />
  }
}
```

and your `ComponentPostList` should be like this...

```
class ComponentPostList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="About">
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="title">{this.props.postTitle}</div>
                    <div className="article">{this.props.changedBody}</div>
                </div>
                {this.props.data.map(el => (
                    <li onClick={e => this.props.handleClick(el.id)} key={el.id}>
                        {el.title}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

On `ComponentArticle`, you use props to access value to render content.

Comment: I got an error in this line this.setState({ post }); ERROR : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.setState is not a function

Comment: It's because my method didn't bind to the class. I've changed my answer to use an arrow function instead. An arrow function can be bind to the class automatically. So it can call any method and property of the class.